# How to fill grouped dynamic Table View cells with content (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dynamic

I'm struggling with grouped dynamic table view. I want to have 2 groups. Basically, in first group I want to have customers data and on second one orders. First group will have always same number of rows. Any what is my problem - I want to put text field into each row of first section (with different placeholder) but when I run application, textfield is only in last row. Does anybody know what Im doing wrong? Thank you

**Declaration of my properties**

```
var textField = UITextField()
var udaje = ["Jméno zákazníka","Kontaktní osoba","Telefon","Email","Fakturační adresa","Dodací adresa","IČO/DIČ"]
```

**TableViewController.swift:**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

var cell = UITableViewCell()

if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("udajeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    self.textField.frame = cell.contentView.frame
    self.textField.placeholder = self.udaje[indexPath.row]

    cell.contentView.addSubview(textField)
} else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("pilyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Přidat pilu"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "+"
}

return cell
}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh yes, Im sorry. Now its correct - In my project I have it correct, I just made mistake here so my question is still the same:)

Comment: use only cell.textField not self.textField. see updated code. @Lachtan

Answer (score 1):

try this way code:

your problem is use use the self.textField. not self.textField use cell.textField.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

var cell = UITableViewCell()

if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("udajeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    cell.textField.frame = cell.contentView.frame
    cell.textField.placeholder = self.udaje[indexPath.row]

    cell.contentView.addSubview(textField)
} else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("pilyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Přidat pilu"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "+"
}

return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but sadly It doesn't work. Just bunch of errors

Comment: you add textfield in Custom cell and set Outlet. @Lachtan

Comment: I did it yesterday viz. my post, but It makes another problems. When I click on Text Field and then on another, the previous TF disappear and console write error: "no index path for table cell being reused"